# Blueprints in Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am taking over a Flask application that has a user module, but does not have a landing page. The structure of the project is:

```
|-application.py
|-manage.py
|-settings.py
|-/templates
|----base.html
|----index.html
|----navbar.html
|----/user
|--------views.py
```

application.py:

```
from flask import Flask

....

def create_app(**config_overrides):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_pyfile('settings.py')

    app.config.update(config_overrides)

    db.init_app(app)

    from user.views import user_app
    app.register_blueprint(user_app)

    return app
```

user/views.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, redirect, session, url_for, abort
...

user_app = Blueprint('user_app', __name__)

@user_app.route('login', methods = ('GET','POST'))
def login():
  ....
```

I placed index.html in the *templates* folder.

Should I place a view.py in the root directory where I would put a route to an index.html?

Answer (score 3):

You can add additional routes anywhere you want.

However, since the package uses a `create_app()` app factory, you can't register those routes with an `@app.route()` decorator; the app is not created in a way you can just import.

So yes, creating a `views.py` module is a good organisational idea, but do create a `Blueprint()` there too, and register that blueprint in the `create_app()` function with the `Flask()` app instance.

In `views.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@main.route('/')
def index():
    # produce a landing page
```

and in `create_app()` in `application.py`, add

```
import views
app.register_blueprint(views.bp)
```

(I use a convention of using the `bp` variable name for all my blueprints, and then just importing the module and registering the `module.bp` attribute).

It's the explicit import and `app.register_blueprint()` call that ties any of the blueprints used in a `Flask` project into the final app's routes. Blueprints can share the same prefix, including having no prefix.

One thing to note: here the `views` module is now a top-level module next to `application.py`. It'd be better if everything was moved into a *package*, giving you more freedom over what names you use. All modules in a single package are namespaced, kept separate from other top-level modules such as `json` and `time` and `flask`, so there won't be clashes when you want to use the same name for one of the additional modules in your project.

You'd move everything but `manage.py` into a subdirectory, with a project-appropriate name, and move `application.py` to `__init__.py`. Imports can then use `from . import ...` to import from the current package, etc.

Comment: thanks, so, the views.py is in the root directory, however, I am getting the following error when "manage.py runserver": Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 7, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "/var/www/my_app/web/application.py", line 19, in create_app
    from . import views
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: @FeyziBagirov: right, I missed that your flask app is a top-level module and not a package, that was my mistake. You really want it to be a package though. I'll update.